# How to sort items in listbox

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, listboxitems

I'm a newbie at programming and I want some help from sorting items in listbox
I have a code for looping which add items on listbox1 what I want is to sort the items into descending order into the other listbox.
For example the output of listbox 1 is 3,6,9 until 39 the sorted descending list will go to listbox2.

```
int thingsforlist;
do{
     listbox.item.add(thingsforlist); 
     thingsforlist = thingforlist+3;
  }
while (thingsforlist<=39);
```

Answer (score 3):

With this function you can sort items you have in a listbox descending or ascending.

```vb
Private Sub sortListBoxItems(ByRef lb As ListBox, ByVal ascending As Boolean)
    Dim items As List(Of Object)
    items = lb.Items.OfType(Of Object)().ToList()
    lb.Items.Clear()
    If ascending Then
        lb.Items.AddRange(items.OrderBy(Function(i) i).ToArray())
    Else
        lb.Items.AddRange(items.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i).ToArray())
    End If
End Sub
```

Or if you prefer C#,

```cs
private void sortListBoxItems(ref ListBox lb, bool ascending)
{
    List<object> items;
    items = lb.Items.OfType<object>().ToList();
    lb.Items.Clear();
    if (ascending)
    { lb.Items.AddRange(items.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray()); }
    else
    { lb.Items.AddRange(items.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToArray()); }
}
```

Comment: this code I think is on C++, but I would try to understand the syntax of this code :). I have not studied C and C++ yet, I started on C#

Comment: @JohnKënnëthIglesia this is VB.Net code. I'm assuming this answer went up before it was clear that you're using C#.

Comment: Originally you had also placed vb.net in your tags.

Comment: im sorry hahaha I thought this was c++ because I rarely see "Dim" on c#. Now I feel so stupid. I should learn more...

Comment: Now there's c# as well.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Why remove the vb.net tag? This is also useful to vb.net coders (especially my answer which includes both languages). Do you know how often I need to search c# questions to answer my vb.net questions? I have nearly become fluent by doing just that. There's no harm in leaving the tag.

Comment: Because it's not a VB.Net question and people need to understand that they are not the same thing. Comments are not the place for this discussion. Take it up on Meta.

Comment: Correct, it's a .NET winforms question. There is no harm in leaving the tag.

Comment: @DanVerdolino vb.NET and c#(.NET) are two horses of different color! It's nowhere near helpful to put them into the same bucket. .NET is not a language. It would be the only thing these two have in common, and it's like comparing pears to apples..

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now.:). Im really sorry for putting vb.net tag

Comment: Google `How to sort items in listbox vb.net` you land here, and you would get your answer. I don't see how it is not constructive to leave the tag.

Comment: @JohnKënnëthIglesia please accept whichever answer helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest a linq sort and then I just thought, you adding numbers in 3s... just do it in reverse and start where you want to end and work backwards.

```
int thingsforlist = 39;
do
{
    listbox.item.add(thingsforlist);
    thingsforlist -= 3;
}
while (thingsforlist > 0);
```

If you had some sort of sortable object you could use linq and `OrderByDescending` but I think you case looks like you don't need to get into that at least based on the code snippet you supplied.

**EDIT:**  Here is another option if you were looking to bind some ordered data:

```
List<int> yourItems = new List<int>();
int thingsforlist = 0;
do
{
    yourItems.Add(thingsforlist);
    thingsforlist += 3;
}
while (thingsforlist <= 39);

listbox.DataSource = yourItems.OrderByDescending(i => i);
listbox.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I was gonna do the same thing you gave me , but I was thinking if I can do it in the other way like sorting the items in descending order.

Comment: @JohnKënnëthIglesia you would need to store the items in such a way that you can store them. Currently you are just incrementing an integer so the values don't exist to be sorted until you have added them to your ListBox so you would need to extract the items, then sort and re-add them or generate them from the start into an object your can sort, then sort, then add them to the list box.

Comment: thanks for helping I would try to understand all fuctions of the codes you gave me. listbox.DataSource = yourItems.OrderByDescending(i => i);
listbox.DataBind();